# names of the marked electronic components in uploaded images

Tags: identification

[image][image]I want to know the names of the marked electronic components. One seems like a capacitor and the other some sort of pcb fuse switch. I want to know their specific name, so that I can search and know more about them. The gray one has "105K63" written on top and the orange one has "40" written on top and "628" written in top right corner.

Comment: @crasic That looks like an answer. You should post it as one!

Comment: @Kevin true, I was wrong anyway.

Answer (score 4):

40A blade type automotive fuse

1uF (105) plastic film cap, 10% (K) 63Vdc
e.g. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cornell-dubilier-electronics-cde/185105K63RGA-F/185105K63RGA-F-ND/1933013